# C++ Parsing Library with UTF-8 support

Tags: c++, parsing, utf-8

Let's say I want to make a parser for a programming language (EBNF already known), and want it  done with as little of a fuss as possible. Also, I want to support identifiers of any UTF-8 letters. And I want it in C++.

`flex`/`bison` have a non-existent UTF-8 support, as I read it. ANTLR seems not to have a working C++ output.

I've considered [boost::spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/), they state on their site it's actually not meant for a full parser.

What else is left? Rolling it entirely per hand?

Comment: I think `boost::spirit` would work fine. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/introduction.html

Comment: You can use AXE C++11 parser generator (with VC2010). It has support for wide characters, you would need to write rules to map UTF8 to wchar_t, which isn't that difficult. wchar_t is required to be able to represent any character from associated locale. No regular expressions though.

Comment: I'm giving boost::spirit a try now, but that seems not too good on the UTF8 either

Comment: boost::spirit has the huge problem of inordinately long compilation times for anything larger than an EBNF of more than a dozen rules.  IMHO it is not usable for real world problems.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504997/minimizing-boostspirit-compile-times

Comment: @ravenspoit: I've now tried `boost::spirit` and that is exactly why I gave up on it. Long compile times and then the cryptic error messages that made it impossible to get further than parsing of a simple 3-rule structure.

Comment: @ravenspoint: If your real world problem is not to write an interpreter for a C-like language, but rather to write a parser for some user supplied data, then spirit would work fine.

Comment: @phresnel I cannot imagine a real world problem for which spirit would be useful.  Homework exercises, sure, but in the real world there are special cases and corner cases each needing the addition of extra rules to handle.  I think spirit is evil.  It is elegant and seems to work well in a test case, so you spend days learning the intricacies - time which is wasted when you realize it is useless in the real world.  Is that why it is called spirit?

Comment: @ravenspoint: I see it as a more complex regex library. When you often work with (legacy) configuration files, or flat text file databases, or address syntax validation (where you have many small grammars for each country in the world), it may have a good place. On the other hand, it often takes too much time to get comfortable with it. I think it is a good EBNF approximation, but I have to admit, if you don't stay in training, it can be tough to work with it. It is somehow good and evil at the same time. Btw, I've written a non-modular LISP-like compiler with it, so I know how bad it can be:)

Comment: @phresnel LISP is a special case. I have written a LISP compiler, implementing CAR and CDR with assembly code and then using LISP to write (bootstrap) the rest of the compiler.  Great fun, but definitely not the real world.

Comment: @ravenspoint: It is part of my real world. I was in need for a pure functional language for the programmatic description of terrain (http://picogen.org, http://picogen.deviantart.com), and I happened to use a subset of LISP. In the meanwhile, I've "fallen back" to a handwritten compiler and a number of optimization passes, because spirit was somehow too much :) Anyways, writing compilers in general is inherently funny, that's a fact :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't find something which has the support you want, don't forget that flex is mostly independant on the encoding.  It lexes an octet stream and I've used it to lex pure binary data.  Something encoded in UTF-8 is an octet stream and can be handled by flex is you accept to do manually some of the work. I.E. instead of having

```
idletter [a-zA-Z]
```

if you want to accept as letter everything in the range Latin1 supplement excepted the NBSP (in other words, in the range U00A1-U00FF) you have to do something like (I may have messed up the encoding, but you get the idea)

```
idletter [a-zA-Z]|\xC2[\xA1-\xFF]|\xC3[\x80-\xBF]
```

You could even write a preprocessor which does most of the work for you (i.e. replaces \u00A1 by \xC2\xA1 and replace [\u00A1-\u00FF] by \xC2[\xA1-\xFF]|\xC3[\x80-\xBF], how much work is the preprocessor depend on how generic you want your input to be, there will be a time when you'd probably better integrate the work in flex and contribute it upstream)

Answer (score 5):

Parsers work on streams of tokens, it's not their duty to understand the encoding. Therefore parsers tend to be encoding agnostic.

What you seem to be asking is about a UTF-8 aware lexer. However, most of the time lexers don't need to be UTF-8 aware either in order to tokenize UTF-8 streams:

For most programming constructs, you will be comparing values of the ASCII  subset of UTF-8 directly. For example, to tokenize a plus operator you compare the byte to '+' as-if it was plain ASCII, and it will work correctly in UTF-8 too by the virtue of UTF-8's ingenuity. Similarly when tokenizing a string literal, you would simply scan till the next occurrence of the quotation mark, including all the UTF-8 bytes in the string as-is; no special handling needed. And I doubt that your goal is to support numbers written with Urdu numerals.

As for identifiers, as a fellow programmer, I'd strongly discourage you from adding support for non-ASCII characters. You could simply assume that all non-ASCII bytes are a part of an identifier, but it's not going to be useful. The issue is not just to classify which characters are considered to be 'letters' according to Unicode, but also to define sensible comparison of those strings later on in your compiler/interpreter. You'd need to determine which normal form to use, and none of those will necessarily match user's expectations.

The bottom line is that, before asking for a "UTF-8 parser", you should first understand some of the complexities of Unicode, and then define which features you'd expect such parser to possess.